# Output numeric formatting is wrong

Tags: c#

I'm writing a program in C# that turns the number (given by an user) to a decimal number with the `$` mark. For example, if i give in 15 then the results should be `$15.00` but the results now is `15.00 ?`.

I have tried to put en-US behind it but it doesn't work

```cs
Console.Write("Give a number that you want to convert to $: ");
int number = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
Console.WriteLine("Money: {0}", number.ToString("C"));
```

**Edit:**
My teacher doesn't allow it to just put "$" in front of it.

Comment: I don't see any problems: https://dotnetfiddle.net/WEU9Ma

Comment: do you need this just for printing?

Comment: `number.ToString("C", CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("en-US"));` doesn't work for you? What's the output of `Console.WriteLine(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.ToString())` on your machine?

Comment: Can you do a `Console.WriteLine(Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture.DisplayName)` and tell us what you see?

Comment: Show us how you “tried to put en-US behind it” and explain what “but it doesn't work” means; did it throw an error? Show us what it wrote.

Answer (score 3):

This should work regardless of your machine's culture info:

```cs
Console.WriteLine("Money: {0}",
  number.ToString("C", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("en-US")));
```